# Calling Several Functions Linked With Classes at Certain Times with AS3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

I'm working on a random wave system for a game. The idea is that every 1000 points a movement pattern would be selected from around 50 possibilities. This would affect the speed, direction, and image of the selected item. I have devised a method that I think will work, but I'm unsure if this is going to cost too much memory to run.

```
public class engine extends MovieClip {

    private var countK:Number = 0;
    private var newWave:Boolean = true;

    public function engine() {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    private function update():void {
        checkCount();
        checkNew();
    }

    private function checkCount():void {
        if (count => 1000) {
            newWave=true;
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    private function checkNew():void {
        if(newWave) {
            randomNumber();
            newWave=false
        }
    }
```

Above is my quick idea of getting a random number to be generated every 1000 points. Points can be added in any way you want (just add say 20 to "Score" and 20 to "count" at the same time). Where I can a random number function in checkNew, I won't be pulling another function, it's simply there for the sake of legibility.

```
                            var newEnemy:mEnemy =new mEnemy();
            stage.addChild(newEnemy);
            EnemyArray.push(newEnemy);
            trace(EnemyArray.length);
```

Above is some code that can add an instance of mEnemy to the stage. Now where I'm starting to loose it is, how can I translate the random number into a viable method of changing mEnemy's behaviour?

Is it wise to have 50 functions inside the mEnemy class and just before I addChild, I do something like newEnemy.WAVEfuncton1(); ? If that is the case, can I save code by getting it to select the function without writing a whole bunch of if statements?

Instead of;

```
if (randomN==1) {
newEnemy.WAVEfunction1();
}
if (randomN==2) {
newEnemy.WAVEfunction2();
}
....
```

Can I do;

```
newEnemy.WAVEfunction[randomN]();
```

This is also assuming that using functions inside the enemy is the best idea. Is it better to have the behaviours inside the engine class instead?

As you can see, I'm no programmer. I'm very new to this sort of thinking and I don't want to create a mistake that will destroy the performance of the game (not to mention picking up bad habits too!).

If you have taken the time to read this question, thank you! If you tolerate my ignorance, then thank you even more!

Comment: Do you know what your waves will do?  Can you just pass the number into a wave generator instead?

Comment: Also, you should use a switch statement and as well as combining the checkCount and checkNew functions

Answer (score 0):

If the wave functions are just creating a single enemy of a certain type, it might make more sense to make an array with the details of each type like this: (I'm guessing at how your enemies work of course)

```
private const ENEMY_TYPES:Array = [
    {speed:1, direction:90, image:1},
    {speed:2, direction:45, image:2}
    ]
```

then change mEnemy() to set itself up according to the details you give it:

```
public function mEnemy(details:Object) {
    mySpeed = details.speed;
    ...
```

That way, you can just write `new mEnemy(ENEMY_TYPES[randomN]);`

Alternatively, if you do need to have lots of separate wave functions, you can use the [[ ]  array access operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access) to access the properties of an object such as `newEnemy` by name (or `this` to reference the current object):

```
var exampleProperty:String = "Hello.";
this["exampleProperty"];
```

So you can run your wave functions by writing:

```
newEnemy["WAVEfunction" + String(randomN)]();
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2-year old question and rather non-actual already but let me try myself here as I have just signed up.

As I understood, what are you proposing to do here is writing all 50 behaviour methods for each kind of Enemy, which is of course not good.

First, you can add the "behaviour" entity. So each enemy now has a behaviour property.

Next, you have to create a separate Behaviour class or interface, which will have 50 subclasses (Behaviour1...Behaviour50), each subclass implementing its own run() method. Note that this way you will be able to add or remove behaviours without touching anything else. A basic implementation would look like this:

```
public class Behaviour() {
    public function run(e:Enemy):void {
       e.y += 10;
    }
}
```

So you see, it's not like enemy is doing something. It's the Behaviour that does something with the enemy it was passed to.

Next, you need a mechanism to get the proper subclass from a given random number.

What you need is a Factory - a static class that will return different types of Behaviours based on input params. Something like this:

```
public class BehaviourFactory {
   public static getBehaviour(n:int):Behaviour {
     switch(n) {
        case 1: return new Behaviour1();
        case 2: return new Behaviour2();
        // etc.
     }
   }
}
```

Instead of having 50 choices inside a switch, you can also use the class definition:

```
var c:Class = getDefinitionByName('Behaviour' + your_random_number) as Class;
return new c;
```

(In further implementatons it can be cached, stored in an Array etc.) After you have a Factory, you just do:

```
var b:Behaviour = BehaviourFactory.getBehaviour(your_random_number);
```

Next, you can use different approaches depending of how exactly the behaviour changes. For example, if the enemy is born with a specific current behaviour and it doesn't change during the enemy's lifetime, you can just assign one of Behaviour subclasses to the Enemy's behaviour property:

```
public class Enemy {
    public var behaviour:Behaviour;
    public function Enemy(b:Behaviour) {
        this.behaviour = b;
    }
}

var e:Enemy = new Enemy(BehaviourFactory.getBehaviour(random_number));
e.behaviour.run(e);
```

This property of course can also be changed dynamically so the next time it is run the enemy will behave differently.

If the behaviour is global for all enemies and changes for all of them at once, you don't event need to have a property in an Enemy object. You just have a global Behaviour object and pass there an Enemy instance:

```
var e:Enemy = enemy_list[i];
current_behaviour.run(e);
```

it will take care of processing each active enemy according to the currently chosen behaviour.

Finally, there's more interesting way to implement behaviours. Suppose you have several behaviour types that don't have anything in common. Say, the Enemy can be Crawling, Flying, Shooting and Poisonous. So let's say you're attempting to implement all possible combinations: Flying, FlyingShooting, FlyingPoisonous, FlyingShootingPoisonous, etc. You would have to create a Behaviour subclass for each of these combinations despite them having very common basic parts.

There's an other way to go, called the Decorator pattern. You simply write a method for each single quality. Whenever you need a combination of qualities, you simply create object with first quality and wrap it into the object with the second quality and wrap it into the object with the third quality etc. So your base Behaviour class needs one addition:

```
public class Behaviour {
    private var parent_bhv: Behaviour;

    public function Behaviour(bhv:Behaviour = null) {
        if (bhv) this.parent_bhv = bhv;
    }

    public function run(e:Enemy):void {
       e.y += 10; // do what we need to do
       if (this.parent_bhv) this.parent_bhv.run(e); // pass to a next bhv.
    }
}
```

Let's create compound behaviour of number 1, 3 and 15:

```
var decorated_behaviour:Behaviour = BehaviourFactory.getDecoratedBehaviour([1, 3, 15]);
```

let's also add the corresponding BehaviourFactory method:

```
public class BehaviourFactory {
    public static function getDecoratedBehaviour(bhv_list:Array):Behaviour {
       var b:Behaviour = null;
       for (var i:int = 0; i < bhv_list.length; i++) {
          var c:Class = getDefinitionByName('Behaviour' + bhv_list[i]) as Class;
          b = new c(b);
       }
       return b;
    }
}
```

Now you're all set without having to code all possible combinations!